# gitignore for jenkins backup, including build artifacts, excluding build directory

Tags: git

So I am trying to setup an automatic jenkins backup using git in the background.
Now I would really like to backup the archived results. However, I don't want/need the rest of this build information (which is a lot).

I've setup my `.gitignore` as:

```
/*snip*/
jobs/**/builds/*
/*snip*/
```

But what I need to add (or so I read) is something like this:

```
/*snip*/
jobs/**/builds/*
!jobs/**/builds/**/archive/*
/*snip*/
```

But that doesn't work. It keeps everything ignored under /builds/*. How do can I un-ignore the archive folder('s) inside the builds/buildnumber/ folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note from the [gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format) documentation:

> It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.

The problem with your pattern is that `jobs/**/builds/*` is excluding all of the numeric build directories *and all directories under them*, so your subsequent negation has no effect because the exclude pattern is a parent of the `archive` directory.

What you need to do is adjust the pattern to exclude the files/directories from within the individual numeric build directory, which still allows you to re-include the `archive` directory

```
jobs/**/builds/*/*
!jobs/**/builds/*/archive
```

Explanation:

1. Exclude all files/directories inside `jobs/<job-name>/builds/<build-no>/`

   - Note the use of the `*` instead of `**`; the single asterisk only matches a single directory instead of expanding to exclude all nested subdirectories
2. Re-include `jobs/<job-name>/builds/<build-no>/archive` (and any files/directories therein)

I've verified that these patterns should work for both freestyle and multibranch pipeline style jobs.